# Static members not initialized - get System.NullReferenceException from array element

Tags: c#, winforms

hit another problem during my C# practise. This is short explanation of it:
In Program.cs I have the following code:

```
namespace testApp
{
  public class AppSettings
  {
    public static int appState { get; set; }
    public static bool[] stepsCompleted { get; set; }
  }

  public void Settings
  {
    appState = 0;
    bool[] stepsCompleted = new bool[]{false, false, false, false, false};
  }
}

static class MyApp
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new gameScreen());
    AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
  }
}
```

And this is in the Form1.Designer.cs:

```
namespace testApp
{
  private void InitializeComponent() {..}
  private void detectPressedKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // Enter = code 13
    {
      if (AppSettings.appState == 0)
      {
        if (AppSettings.stepsCompleted[1] == false) // << here we have an EXCEPTION!!!
        {
          this.playSound("warn");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is in the commented `if` where I get `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Searched a bit through the net but cannot find where is the problem. `AppSettings.stepsCompleted` should exist like `AppSettings.appState`

Comment: You are not assigning anything non-null to `AppSettings.stepsCompleted`, so it will be null. It does exist, but it doesn't have a value, so attempting to access its elements will throw a NRE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't initializing the `AppSettings.stepsCompleted` anywhere. In fact, `testApp.Settings` won't compile. Since your `AppSettings` class has static members, which you access from your form, and assuming you need only a single instance to track state, what you can do is initialize them via a [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

```
public static class AppSettings // May as well make the class static 
{
  public static int appState { get; set; }
  public static bool[] stepsCompleted { get; set; }

  static AppSettings() // Static constructor
  {
    appState = 0;
    stepsCompleted = new []{false, false, false, false, false};
  } 
}
```

You then need to remove the line from `Main`:

```
AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
```

Static constructors are guaranteed to be invoked once, prior to the first access

**Edit - Full working sample**

*Program.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testApp
{
    public static class AppSettings // May as well make the class static 
    {
        public static int appState { get; set; }
        public static bool[] stepsCompleted { get; set; }

        static AppSettings() // Static constructor
        {
            appState = 0;
            stepsCompleted = new[] { false, false, false, false, false };
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new gameScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

*Form1.cs (gameScreen)*

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testApp
{
    public partial class gameScreen : Form
    {
        public gameScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void gameScreen_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // Enter = code 13
            {
                if (AppSettings.appState == 0)
                {
                    if (AppSettings.stepsCompleted[1] == false)
                    {
                        this.playSound("warn");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void playSound(string someSound)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sound : {0}", someSound));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, did your suggestions and I've got the same exception

Comment: ... but realized that I should remove `bool[]` in front of stepsCompleted in the constructor, in fact I missed it :). Now it works, answer approved! Btw Im'm using embedded resource for playSound().

Comment: Apols - I didn't notice that change -  `new []{false, false, false, false, false}` and `new bool[]{false, false, false, false, false}` should both work - the compiler can infer that its an array of booleans. My Resharper cleanup is set to remove anything it deems redundant.